# Local Homeomorphisms and Fundamental Groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and suppose we have a local homeomorphism $f : X \to Y.$ With respect to any basepoint in $X,$ under what conditions will we have an injective induced map on the fundamental groups?

I know that this will be the case if $f$ is a covering map, but are there more general criteria under which injectivity will follow?